# Javascript callback with database

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am new to Javascript and call back functions. is this the correct way to do a call back? when i test i get an infinite loop. I want to retrieve from the database and store in an object's variable to use in getSport().

```
constructor(matchid) {
    this.hasLoaded = false;
    this.matchid = mid;
    this.Match = {
        "sport": "baskt",
        "winner": -1,
    };
}
rload(callback) {
    this.hasLoaded = true;
    matchDataBaseRef.child(this.mid)
        .on("value", function (snapshot) {
            this.Match = snapshot.val();
            callback();
        });
}
get getSport() {
    if (!this.hasLoaded) {
        this.rload(this.getSport);
    }
    return this.Match['sport'];
}
```

Comment: You cannot return synchronously from `getSport` if it calls an asynchronous function. You should read [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). You also have a problem with `this`, see [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) for that.

Comment: These are all from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=frequent btw.

Comment: `this.getSport` is a getter, not a function - and the getter recursively calls itself ad infinitum, er, stack overflow.

Comment: If I realized correctly, the behavior you want seems match to the [ES6 generator](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators) pattern. That is, do `getSport` asynchronouslly, then `yield` `rload` result, then do `getSport` again ..., until some condition matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right approach. You are trying to synchronize in `this.getSport`. Instead, you should have your initialization inside the callback and do not infinitely call it. Let's suppose you have something like this:

```
function myTask(params) {
    //do something
    params.callback();
    //do something
}
```

then you should not work with that like this unless you have a very good reason:

```
var foo = function() {
    myTask({callback: foo});
};
```

Instead of it, in most cases you need something like this:

```
var foo = function(cb) {
    myTask({callback: cb});
};
```

`cb` needs to be defined though separately. So do not pass the wrapper function as a callback if that is not precisely what you want to do.